# date_select issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented date_select in my views when i access it in to model it gives me error:

View:

```
<%= date_select :transaction ,:card_expires_on,:discard_day => true, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => (Date.today.year+10), :add_month_numbers => true, :order => [:month,:year]%>
```

Model:

```
 def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
      :type               => card_type,
      :number             => card_number,
      :verification_value => card_verification,
      :month              => card_expires_on.month,
      :year               => card_expires_on.year,
      :first_name         => first_name,
      :last_name          => last_name
    )
  end
```

error:

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.month
```

Comment: Please format your question to make the code readable. You can use the "{}" button at the top bar of the editor.

Comment: I don't see how @credit_card relates to the date_select.  Can you post the class definition for the model and the <%= form_for %> tag you're using?

Answer (score 2):

Based on what you've posted, I'd say that `card_expires_on` in your credit_card method is nil.